# Get ConnectionString from app.config

Tags: c#

I'm pretty sure there's some quick and easy error in this code but somehow I've spent the last 2 hours with this and couldn't solve it.

`App.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BO"
        connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=BO;User ID=WebUser;Password=MyPasswd"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

`Class.cs`:

```
string connectionString = getNewConnection();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) { code }
```

Method.

```
public static string getNewConnection()
{
   return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BO"].ConnectionString;
 }
```

Error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on the line :

```
return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BO"].ConnectionString;
```

EDIT:

[image: Error image, the Spanish sentence means: Object reference not set to an instance of an object]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BO"].ConnectionString;
```

**Edit:**

You will need the corresponding libraries as well if you don't have them yet, as mentioned in the below answers I think its System.Configuration

**So in full you should have:**

```
public static string getNewConnection()
{
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BO"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: Corrected the library, it is System.Configuration

Comment: if I use "ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connections = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BO"].ConnectionString;" I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection'"

Comment: You don't need to do that, in your getNewConnection() function simply have `return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BO"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: the same error pops up in that line. Weird, would my app.config be wrong?

Comment: It looks right, try putting it all on one line. Also make sure it is in the right config file if this system has more than one.

Comment: Just one config file, still same error. I've added a photo of the debugger, maybe it helps

Comment: Odd, and you did put `using System.Configuration;` in? It definitely  looks like it is not finding that config file or at least not that connection string in it. Make sure you saved the config file.

Comment: Yes, Im "using System.Configuration;" and I've referenced the .dll manually into the project. It's so annoying. Thanks a lot anyways

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure what is going on then, I'd suggest testing to see if you can pick up other values from that same config file, either other connection strings or app settings. If you can't then it really looks like an issue with it not looking at the right file. If you can then it looks like a syntax issue.

Comment: it's solved! the app.config was in the same project as the class.cs, but for testing purposes I had created a new one with a windows form containing a datagrid with a simple select * from table from the desired server. I had to put the app.config inside that one project. (the reference was made to the Class.cs project so I didn't think that could matter at all) but indeed it did matter... I knew it was something that silly. Thanks a lot for your patience and help.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer in case someone else ends up having this same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use these codes in the Class :

```
class Connection
    {
        public static string con
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sql"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it gives me the same error (now referencing to your line of code). Would my app.config be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the WebConfigurationManager?

```
string MyConnectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BO"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: it says System.Web does not containg .Configuration etc. (I have added using System.Web )

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to System.Configuration.dll, and you should be able to use the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.